# Append to a Elasticsearch field list/array if it's not an existing element

Tags: elasticsearch

Say we have:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/t/t/1" -d'
{
     "hobbies" : ["a", "b"]
}'
```

I know I can do this to append to hobbies:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/t/t/1/_update" -d'
{
     "script" : "ctx._source.hobbies += hobby",
     "params" : {
         "hobby" : "c"
     }
}'
```

But how can I do it so if hobby isn't 'c' but is 'b', I won't end up with ["a", "b", "b"] for hobby? So it only appends "c" if "c" isn't a hobby already?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can achieve the same by modifying the script in OP a little

Example :

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/t/t/1/_update -d'
{
     "script" : " if(! ctx._source.hobbies.contains(hobby)){ ctx._source.hobbies += hobby }",
     "params" : {
         "hobby" : "c"
     }
}'
```

The above  example assumes that field *hobbies* exists and is a *List* else you would need to incorporate a bit more logic to handle these.